# Is it possible to remove prefetch cache settings from sitecore version 8.X?

Tags: configuration

I want to disable the prefetch cache settings. Is there any way to disable them? I tried deleting the files from prefetch folder but site throws exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use Sitecore's config patches to remove the caches. For example:

```
<sitecore>
    <databases>
        <database id="core">
            <dataProviders hint="list:AddDataProvider">
                <dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)">
                    <prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
                        <patch:delete />
                    </prefetch>
                </dataProvider>
            </dataProviders>
        </database>
    </databases>
</sitecore>
```

Comment: Reason for the error is that the Sitecore.config file defines a path for those prefetch configs that you deleted. You have to apply a patch for all 3 databases: core, master and web.

Comment: @Trayek , Thanks for the detail and . I will try this patch  .

Comment: @KoenHeye - I just see that now the file paths are there is in the sitecore.config . Thanks !!

Comment: @JTC - I want to stress that you should use a patch file to override the sitecore.config as Trayek described!

Comment: @JTC If this solved the issue, please mark it as the answer :-)